# PHP/MySQL Select Content per ID

Tags: php, mysql, oop

What I want is to show my content per ID

This is my code:

```
class content
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($myDB)
    {
        $this->connection = $myDB;
    }

    public function showContent()
    {

        $array = $this->connection->query4Array("SELECT `content` FROM `data` WHERE id ");

        $rows = '';
        foreach($array as $result)
        {
            $rows .= $result['content'];
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

This is my info page, but it shows now all the content from all the other pages out of my database: the ID of my info page is 2.

**Info page code.**

```
include('/../../library/content.php');
$db = new Connection("portfolio", "root", "");
$contentShow = new content($db);
$content = $contentShow->showContent();

echo $content;
```

Comment: You need to use `WHERE id=2` inside your SQL. Pass in a parameter to your `showContent` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your PHP classes starting with an uppercase letter.
Further, use this:

```
class Content
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($myDB)
    {
        $this->connection = $myDB;
    }

    public function showContent($id)
    {

        $array = $this->connection->query4Array("SELECT `content` FROM `data` WHERE id = " . $id);

        $rows = '';
        foreach($array as $result)
        {
            $rows .= $result['content'];
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

and

```
include('/../../library/content.php');
$db = new Connection("portfolio", "root", "");
$contentShow = new Content($db);
$content = $contentShow->showContent(2);

echo $content;
```